# SurfaceView has two buffer?

Tags: android, canvas, surfaceview

the android offical said:"On each pass you retrieve the Canvas from the `SurfaceHolder`, the previous state of the Canvas will be retained. In order to properly animate your graphics, you must re-paint the entire surface. For example, you can clear the previous state of the Canvas by filling in a color with `drawColor()` or setting a background image with `drawBitmap()`. Otherwise, you will see traces of the drawings you previously performed."

Then I write some code to verify the two buffer.The code is as follow:

```java
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private SurfaceView iv;
    private int flag=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        iv=(SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.sv);

    }
    public void draw(View view){

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                Paint paint=new Paint();

                SurfaceHolder holder1 = iv.getHolder();

                RectF r=new RectF(300,300,600,600);
                switch(flag){
                case 0: {Canvas canvas=holder1.lockCanvas();
                        canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
                        holder1.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                        Log.d("ddd",flag+"");
                        flag++;}
                        break;
                case 1:
                    {Canvas canvas=holder1.lockCanvas();
                    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
                    holder1.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                    Log.d("ddd",flag+"");
                    flag++;}
                    break;
                case 2:
                {
                    Canvas canvas=holder1.lockCanvas();
                    holder1.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                    Log.d("ddd",flag+"");
                }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
    }
```

the xml file is as follow:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="划线"
        android:onClick="draw"/>
    <SurfaceView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/sv"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

If the `SurfaceView` has two buffer,then when the `flag==2` ,the front buffer is blue and the behind buffer is red.So when I click the button the `SurfaceView` will change its color between red and blue.But the fact is that `SurfaceView` change its color among red,blue and black(the `SurfaceView's` background color is black by default).Does `SurfaceView` has three buffers?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to tell how many buffers SurfaceView is using.  Even if you determine it experimentally, it's allowed to change out from under you.

Generally speaking, if you send SurfaceView buffers at a moderate pace (perhaps using [Choreographer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Choreographer.html)), it will be double-buffered.  If you send it buffers rapidly, it will switch to triple-buffering.  The reason for this is explained in the [graphics architecture doc](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html).

You can reasonably assume that there will be more than one buffer, though, and that the previous contents will not be erased for you.  So you need to draw every pixel inside the dirty region, which defaults to the entire screen.